# Obtaining dates when a process changes task

Tags: activiti

Is there a way to obtain dates when a Process starts a Task? For example, I have a Process called `test` and it has tasks `start`, `middle`, `end`, and `review`. Is it possible to obtain the dates that these four tasks started for a specific process given a process variable?

I tried searching for this and couldn't find any information. The closest thing I got was the Querying History in the Activiti Documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to get start/end date of each task from [HistoryTaskInstance](http://activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/history/HistoricTaskInstance.html) object which you can retrive by making [HistoryTaskInstanceQuery](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#historyQueryTaskInstance)